# Вывести первый положительный элемент списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
x = [-3, -5, 4, 2, -2, -6, 5]
for i in x:
    if x[i] > 0:
        print(x[i])
```

Не могу понять что не правильно и почему выводит результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если x = [-3, -5, 3, 4, 2, -2, -6, 5].
Тогда выводит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как сделать чтобы в первом случае вывело только 4, а во втором 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

а попробуйте так:

```
x = [-3, -5, 4, 2, -2, -6, 5]
print(list(filter(lambda i: i > 0, x))[0])
```

Comment: все работает, спасибо

Comment: @Zhihar - `next()` тут лучше list()[0]

Answer (score 7):

Варианты @Zhihar, @NykSu проходят весь список, а достаточно получить только один первый элемент из генератора:

```
print(next(filter(lambda i: i > 0, x)))
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
x = [-3, -5, 4, 2, -2, -6, 5]
for i in x:
    if i > 0:
        print(i)
        break # Прерывает цикл
```

i по сути и есть элемент x, а не его индекс. В первой итерации у Вас получается x[-3], во второй x[-5] и тд...
Дублирование из за того что x[-5] это 4, и x[2] тоже указывает на 4.

Comment: тупая ошибка, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```py
if условие:
    #ваш код
    break
```

Тогда программа выйдет из цикла и не будет проверять другие елементы

Comment: Это точно Python? )

Answer (score 2):

Можно и такой код, как вариант:

```
lst = [-3, -5, 4, 2, -2, -6, 5]
print([x for x in lst if x > 0][0])
```

Хоть выше с циклом быстрее выполнится.

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю функционального изврата, раз уж все пишут разные варианты. )

```
from operator import lt
from functools import partial
lst = [-3, -5, 4, 2, -2, -6, 5]
print(next(filter(partial(lt, 0), lst)))
```